# mock final classes for both unit and UI tests

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mockito, ui-testing

I am trying to write both unit and espresso UI test for my android app, build with kotlin. Since in kotlin every class is final by default so to mock a final class I have used mockInline library which supports mocking final classes. 
Since I have to write both unit and UI tests. I have added the library in the following way

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
```

But on running UI tests It is throwing

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker'
```

Is there a way to use the mockInline library to mock final classes for both unit and UI tests

Comment: Rather than using mocktio with a plugin to test Kotlin, I would use a mocking framework written (in and) for Kotlin, like https://mockk.io/

Comment: Have you tried using PowerMockito?

Comment: Thanks, but I am still looking if there is a way to use the mockito-Inline library for both tests. Of course PowerMickito and mockk.io are last options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not mock final classes for UI Tests(Android Test) using mockito inline plugin as mentioned on official issue tracker [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1173#issuecomment-324401986)

The reason behind that is

> "There is no real possibility to make this work in Android at the
>   moment as it lacks the instrumentation API on top of which we are
>   operating. The Android VM is not a standard VM and only implements a
>   subset of the Java specification. As long as Google does not choose to
>   extend its JVM, I am afraid that this feature will not work."

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1173#issuecomment-325130572)

To mock final classes for android Tests

- We can use [DexOpener](https://github.com/tmurakami/dexopener) library with the ability to mock final classes in Android.
- We can also use [Kotlin Open Plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html) which makes all final classes open without explicit open keyword.